# Using jq to print out multiple elements in json

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to get `jq` to return both the keyname as well as the isAvailable value. This offering is currently not available in every region that is being returned by the API so I would ideally like to be able to return something like the following:

```
[
  "AMSTERDAM03,
  "1"
]
```

Here is the json being returned by the API call.

```
[
    {
        "description": "AMS03 - Amsterdam",
        "keyname": "AMSTERDAM03",
        "location": {
            "location": {
                "id": 814994,
                "longName": "Amsterdam 3",
                "name": "ams03",
                "statusId": 2
            },
            "locationPackageDetails": [
                {
                    "isAvailable": 1,
                    "locationId": 814994,
                    "packageId": 737
                }
            ]
        },
        "sortOrder": 2
    }
]
```

If I run `jq '.[] | .keyname'` I get back the expected value, but I cannot seem to figure out the syntax for digging in to the lower layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `jq` filter like below would be sufficient,

```
command-producing-json | jq '.[] | [ .keyname, .location.locationPackageDetails[].isAvailable ]'
```

would produce below as expected.

```
[
  "AMSTERDAM03",
  1
]
```

You can lose the double-quotes by using the `-r`, `--raw-output` option.

Comment: It's not so easy to lose the double-quotes without also losing the JSON structure.   Adding the -r option here will not make any difference as the output is an array.